# Installing Ruby gem 'cocoapods' fails

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fastlane

I try to incorporate cocoapods into my fastlane build. Acording to the [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/cocoapods/) that should be as easy as adding a single line to my Fastfile:

```
cocoapods
```

This should then call `pod install` for me. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead of just calling `pod install` the fastlane try's to install cocoapods which then fails:

```
[16:32:36]: Installing Ruby gem 'cocoapods'...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
+------------------+-----------------+
|            Lane Context            |
+------------------+-----------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios             |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios             |
| LANE_NAME        | ios kptapp_TEST |
+------------------+-----------------+
[16:32:52]: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/Caskroom/fastlane/latest/fastlane_lib/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/usr/local/Caskroom/fastlane/latest/fastlane_lib/bundle/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200309-76244-14k7phf.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

What is particularly strange: cocoapods is already installed:

```
>which pod                   
/usr/local/bin/pod
```

No need to install it. As said the documentation doesn't say anything about this. Any hints or pointer.

## UPDATE 1:

Noted something interesting. When calling `fastlane env` I get:

```
| Key                         | Value                                                                |
| --------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Ruby                        | 2.2.4                                                                |
```

But the actually installed rub is:

```
>ruby --version
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

Looks like fastlane is using the wrong ruby.